# FTPS in Laravel not working (SSL write failed)

Tags: php, laravel, ftps

So I am trying to transfer a file via FTPS in Laravel. I am using this code to create a disk

```
public function disk(){
        $protocol = $this->protocol;
        if($this->protocol == "ftps"){
            $protocol = "ftp";
        }
        $disk = Storage::build([
            'driver' => $this->protocol,
            'host' => $this->ip,
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password' => $this->password,
           
            'ssl' => true,
            'passive' => true
        ]);

        return $disk;
    }
```

And I am calling the function within this code-block and try to upload a file:

```
public function upload(ImportedImage $image){
        $filepath = "path/to/file";

        if($this->protocol == "ftp" || $this->protocol == "ftps"){
          
            $this->disk()->putFileAs($this->folder, $filepath, $image->original_name);
            return "ok";
        }

 
    }
```

But I get this error

`ErrorException: ftp_fput(): SSL write failed in /var/www/html/zendee/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Ftp.php:275`

The object I am accessing has correct a username/password combination, I can access the server via cyberduck/filezilla, so that's not the issue. The protocol is "ftps", (so it gets changed to "ftp" in the "disk" function).

I have already looked into similar problems which where solved by the "passive" parameter. I tried every possible combination of the "ssl" and "passive" option - didn't help unfortunately.
It also said somewhere that I should configure my FTP-Server to allow ssl-only, so I also did that.

Thanks for every kind of help.

Comment: Why are you changing `protocol` to ftp for ftps connections?

Comment: Unfortunately Laravel doesn't seem to support this option

Comment: I am still not sure it will work, but I think I spotted a simple mistake - you set `$protocol = "ftp"`, but then you use `$this->protocol` for driver.  So protocol does not really switch to ftp.  If that's the problem, I'll add it as an answer ...

Comment: Oh you are absolutely correct. But I tried it with the $protocol variable and even hard-coded "ftp". Both won't work.

Comment: Still guessing, but I notice you did not specify a `root`, have you tried doing that?  Do you have access to the server, can you check the logs there?

Comment: [Reading the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#automatic-streaming), `putFileAs()` is a special method for *streaming* files, and the 2nd parameter needs to be "*either an `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instance*".  You are simply passing a string, the path to your file.  Is the file already on disk, or is this part of a file upload, or ... ?

Comment: Hm it is not part of a file upload, so the file already is on the disk. I tried it with the new File($filepath) method, but it doesn't seem to make any difference